# Reading from an external file in Javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, file-io, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to read from an external text file `map.txt` (allocated in my own server, not in the client's computer) and to store the data contained in it in a bi-dimensional array `map[][]` using Javascript.

The `map.txt` file would be filled with numbers and each of it's rows has a fixed length:

```
21123301201200
12030201303321
22321321021312
12312310001230
12312321221220
```

So, I want it to store it in the bi-dimensional array `map` in such a way that `map[0][0] = 2` and `map[13][4] = 0` -in this example-. Is this even possible to do? And if so, how is it done?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Javascript on the server-side or just on the client-side? And do you want the server or the client to read the file?

Comment: I'm using Javascript on the client-side and I want the client to read the file (but the file itself is allocated in the server, not in the client's computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the file. Have a look at: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

And use this function to create the array:

```
function handleRequest(req){
    var a=req.responseText.split('\n');
    var len=a.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        a[i]=a[i].split('');
    }
    return a;
}
```

This function should return:

```
[["2","1","1","2","3","3","0","1","2","0","1","2","0","0"],
["1","2","0","3","0","2","0","1","3","0","3","3","2","1"],
["2","2","3","2","1","3","2","1","0","2","1","3","1","2"],
["1","2","3","1","2","3","1","0","0","0","1","2","3","0"],
["1","2","3","1","2","3","2","1","2","2","1","2","2","0"]]
```

Use `map[4][13]` instead of `map[13][4]` to get the last element in your example